# android emulator is not starting

Tags: java, android, android-studio, haxm

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.

**Output:**

> emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum
>   of 128MB emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 128MB
>   qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive
>   if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=C:\Users\haris.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_19.avd/cache.img:
>   could not open disk image
>   C:\Users\haris.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_19.avd/cache.img: Could not
>   open 'C:\Users\haris.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_19.avd/cache.img':
>   Invalid argument Hax is enabled Hax ram_size 0x20000000 HAX is working
>   and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your Android Studio  `open Windows`->`Select Android Virtual Device Manager`->`Chose your device`->`Click Edit button`->`Change the RAM parameter to 172 MB in the Memory Options`->`Save and run`the emulator it will work